Установка заголовков Last-Modified и If-Modified-Since в 1СБитрикс
для установки заголовков Last-Modified и If-Modified-Since использовал эту инструкцию. Но у меня остались некоторые вопросы:

правильно ли я понял что нужно проделать все это для каждого компонента на сайте?

правильно ли я понял что для статических страниц нужно просто установить этот код в хедер?
  GLOBAL $lastModified;
  if (!$lastModified){    
   $lastModified = strtotime(date("D, d M Y H:i:s", 
   filectime($_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME'])));
  }




Для каждого компонента - нет, не надо. Только для того компонента на странице, который предоставляет основную информацию.
Да, можно в хедер. Для статических страниц тогда $lastModified будет установлена в хедере, а для динамических $lastModified будет в последующем переписана в соответствующем компоненте.

на самом деле я так и сделал, но это не сработало. а если на странице находится компонент и включаемая область, это статическая страница или динамическая?

Поскольку включаемая область может быть отредактирована, то это - динамическая страница. Необходимо учитывать время изменения включаемой области.

с включаемыми областями все так же как с компонентами работает?

Да. Только нужно не просто заменять $lastModified, а смотреть предыдущее значение (если есть) и заменять время только на более новое.

можно подробнее? я не очень дружу с битриксом

На странице может быть несколько компонентов. Если один ставит одно время, а другой - другое, то может получиться неправильно. Первый ставит изменение на сегодня, а второй меняет на неделю назад.
